# Where can I find the dimensions of an object?

Tags: interface, transforms

In earlier Blender versions, the "Transform Properties" panel showed the object dimensions (i.e., bounding box: width, height, depth).  Now, it just shows location, rotation, and scale.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the *Properties Panel* of the 3D View, the *Dimensions* are listed below *Scale* in the *Transform* panel (bottom right):

[image: 3D View with N-panel opened]

Comment: Thanks, I had been looking at the object "Transform" panel instead.

Answer (score 5):

While CoDEmanX's answer is still correct for Blender 2.8, you have to have the **Modeling view mode** (bar at the top) selected and be in **object mode** for the dimensions to appear in the transform panel.
User serdar.sanri added this information [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135215/where-did-object-dimensions-go-in-2-8), however this question pops up first in the google search, so it might help to find this comment here, too.

As of Blender 3.0, Modelling view is no longer required.