# How to precisely resize an edge or face?

Tags: modeling

Say I have a pipe and it's diameter is 23 cm, but I want it to be 10, how would I scale it so that I could type in "10" and it'd then scale to be 10cm in diameter?

if that's not possible then for separate edges if I wanted one to be 10cm could I just type 10 into the numpad and it'll become 10cm? when I've tried this it seems to just scale up by a magnitude. And I can't seem to find a panel that'll let me change the dimensions of an edge or face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Dimensions sliders in the 3D view properties panel. Press <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D view, or go to View -> Properties. To use the units you want, go to the Properties panel -> Scene -> Units panel. In your case, select "Metric". Then change the dimensions as needed. You type in the number followed by the units (you don't need a space between the number and units). In the screenshot below, I set the X and Y axes to 10cm so the cylinder ends are a circle with diameter 10cm.

[image]

For separate edges, you can't directly make an edge 10cm. For some edges, you can use vertex snapping to get what you what. In the example below, I used a plane instead of a single edge because it's easier to see.

[image]

So for a face in edit mode, you'd have to consider it as edges you have to resize and change your select mode to Edge Select.

Other notes about Dimensions:

- Note that 1 Blender unit ["None"] is equal to 1 meter. (Interestingly enough, this may not be right when 3D printing. When I tried it for the first time at my university, I found out that the machine I wanted to use read 1 Blender unit = 1 mm, so when I was using "Metric", 15 cm = 0.15 m = .15 Blender units = 0.15 mm, which is like microscopic. Got a good laugh out of that.)
- You can't type unit abbreviations when the units are set to "None".
- You can type imperial unit abbreviations even when you select "Metric", and vice versa. This can be handy when you need to convert units.
- Dimensions represent the bounding box of an object. So if you rotate an object in edit mode, the Dimensions won't reflect the object's actual dimensions.
- Dimensions are independent of scale, whether you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to Apply Scale or not.
- Dimensions are relative to Local axes. This can make things confusing, like if the cylinder in the first image was rotated 90 degrees in on the y axis, changing the X dimensions would make it seem like it's being scaled along the z-axis. Change the Transform orientation in the 3D view to "Local" if you need to.

See also [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/set-dimensions-of-a-mesh) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/where-can-i-find-the-dimensions-of-an-object).

Comment: @Vubien Sure. You can mark this answer as your accepted answer, or accept the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I guess the picture should say it all?