# Where did object dimensions go in 2.8?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, units

Anyone seen this panel? Essential for precise modeling.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Edit Mode dimensions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86829/edit-mode-dimensions)

Answer (score 25):

Same as in 2.7.

Press <kbd>N</kbd> while in **Object Mode**.

[image]

Or press on the little < sign on the right of the screen to bring out the window. If the transform section has been minimized, press on the triangle to expand it.

[image]

Comment: Crap... I was looking for it in edit mode. Thanks!!

Comment: Also one side note, your view mode on top bar should be Modeling. Layout seems very similar and opens in that mode default but you don't see the Transform options in panel in that case

Comment: As stated above, this option is apparently only in Object mode. Very powerful feature!

Comment: In the most recent version of Blender i additionally had to select the "Item" tab in the window on the right to see the "Transform" dialog that holds the dimension options.

Comment: Thanks, @serdar.sanri!! +1!