# Dimensions not shown under Transform panel

Tags: dimensions

I am unable to find where you can type in the dimensions of an object. Scale, transform etc are all there but not dimensions. I am trying to edit the active object under the Properties/Data menu. I can successfully scale the object but I need to be able to type in values.

I found this question but the answer did not help, i.e. that you had to be in Object mode.  It does not matter if I am in Object or Edit mode.

I am using 2.91.

I guess I'm doing something daft or missing something so please take pity :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where did object dimensions go in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135215/where-did-object-dimensions-go-in-2-8)  see also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86829/edit-mode-dimensions

Comment: btw it does matter re edit and object mode. The unit size (dimension) of an object is defined by its bounding box data, what we see in edit mode. eg a mesh for a mesh object.  eg default cube unit size is 2x2x2.  In knowing the unit size can link dimension and scale. Edit mode is changing unit size. Zeroing on an axis will cause issues in conversion.  Btw not sure why we have so many new user downvote snipers, like shooting fish in a barrel, have an upvote in protest.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. Unfortunately, I am still not able to set dimensions no matter which menu I go through. The link to the Bforartists 2 looks interesting so I may try that, but I would prefer to stick with Blender for now. Guess I'll risk another question but with screenshots  ... :-)