# Cannot set dimensions

Tags: dimensions

I can't set dimensions, looked really easy according to questions answered more than one year ago but I swear I am doing my best and have come up stumped. batFINGER gave me some pointers and I tried them but honestly I cannot see where I am going wrong.

On my menu there is nothing about setting dimensions (see drop down and also workspace on the right). Just scaling.

[image: Screenshot of where menu should be]

Comment: In your previous question one of the comments points to another question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135215/where-did-object-dimensions-go-in-2-8 which points out to press **N** key. As well as to use the *Modelling* tab.

Comment: I was just going to answer my own question: I just spotted that! Yaaaaay. Cheers everyone!

Answer (score 3):

As @Markus von Broady pointed out, editing an objects dimensions is available in the N-Panel (hit <kbd>n</kbd> key) but not in edit mode, you need to be in object mode.

[image]

Changing any of the dimensions will also change the scale, so be sure to apply scale if you're doing any deformations, physics, etc.

There are other ways to get accurate dimensions while modeling in edit mode but that's for another question :)